# e+number meaning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

In a data frame, I have a column that has values such as `1.504210e+12`

How do I display these numbers in Float Format?

Here is a part of that column.

```
1        1.504130e+12
2        1.504130e+12
3        1.504110e+12
4        1.504030e+12
             ...     
20053    1.499791e+12
20054    1.499698e+12
20055    1.499698e+12
20056    1.499696e+12
20057    1.499643e+12
```

Comment: If your pandas dataframe is named `df` => `df.round(5)` will help (Replace 5 with the number of places you desire).  This website will be helpful - https://re-thought.com/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-in-pandas/